# MS SQL Server Bulk insert can't find file path

Tags: sql-server

I am using BULK INSERT to insert data from csv file in ms ssql database

```
BULK INSERT JmeterSummaryReport
FROM '\\SF-test\share\Result_2023-05-03_12-42.csv'

WITH 
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
```

The above query works but I want to parametrize this part of the path Result_2023-05-03_12-42.csv' in order to get current date.

```
I did this:

DECLARE @currentTime VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(50);
SET @currentTime = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108), ':', 
'-');
SET @currentTime = '_' + RIGHT('00' + SUBSTRING(@currentTime, 1, 2), 
2) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + 
SUBSTRING(@currentTime, 4, 2), 2);
SET @Result = 'Result_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 
23)+@currentTime
SET @Path = '\\SF-test\share\'
DECLARE @fullPath NVARCHAR(50) =CONCAT(@Path, @Result)
```

And when print @fullPath got exactly what I want - \SF-test\share\Result_2023-05-04_13-30

Then I Put @fullPath in bulk insert query and got error:

> Cannot bulk load. The file "'+@fullPath'" does not exist or you don't have file access rights.

```
BULK INSERT JmeterSummaryReport
FROM '''+@fullPath'''
 

WITH 
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
```

Where I am wrong, maybe escaping issue or something else?

Comment: I think you want `'''' + @fullPath + ''''`

Comment: `BULK INSERT` expects a literal for the path, and T-SQL doesn't support variable substitution; `'@fullPath'` is a *literal string* with the value `'@fullPath'`, *not* a literal string with that has the value *stored* within the variable `@fullPath`. You would need to use dynamic SQL here, but you'll also want to try and ensure that you can't suffer SQL injection.

Comment: to elaborate ThomA's answer, you want something like: exec('bulk insert ... from ''' + @fullpath + ''' with field...') the quotes are a bit tricky to get right, you need to escape every quote by another one